# Best method for storing data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a pretty basic question on which is the preferred way of storing data in my database.

I have a table called "users" with each user getting a username and user_id. Now, I want to make a table called "comments" for users to comment on news.

Is it better to have a column in comments called "username" and storing the logged in user's name, or have a column called "user_id". If I use user_id I would have to make my sql statement have another select statement. "(SELECT username FROM users WHERE users.id = comments.user_id) as username". It seems like performance would be better just storing the username.

I thought I read to avoid duplicate data in a database though.

Which is better?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Typically, you use ID fields to link tables together.  The reason being (in your situation) that you might allow the person to change their username, but you don't want to try and update all the places that is at...

Therefore, put the user_id in your comments table and pull the username out on a join, as you've shown.

Comment: Yep, exactly right. Maybe one thing : I *always* use the name "id" for ALL my tables if it's the "main" id, and a foreign key begin with "id_" then the name of the table of the forgein key. Thus my queries look like :

<<SELECT C.comment FROM users U JOIN comment C ON C.id_user=U.id WHERE U.name like "Olivier">>. What's the point ? Someone who doesn't know your database will very easily guess the syntax of the foreign keys, and (far more important) in the long run your database is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

If the user_id is the primary key then you should use user_id instead of username, if you want to use username instead of user_id then why do you have a user_id in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

If there's the potential of creating a large enough database, store the user_id in the comments table.  Less overhead.  Also consider that usernames my be modified easier this way.

Comment: Just to clarify, I think you meant that if they use usernames, then they'd encounter slower JOINs, right?

Answer (score 1):

Data should be stored in (at least) [third normalized form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), so you should use the user_id as the primary key in the users table, and as a foreign key in the comments table and use this to get the details:

```
SELECT comments.*, users.username  
FROM comments, users
WHERE users.user_id = comments.user_id;
```

If you are getting the comments based on an article, you could do this like this:

```
SELECT comments.*, users.username  
FROM comments, users
WHERE users.user_id = comments.user_id  
AND comments.article_id = '$current_article_id';
```

Comment: You don't need the articles table in that second query at all.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the userid (integer) will mean faster JOINs later. Unless you plan on having people dig through the database by hand, there's really no reason to use the username

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure storing the user id in the comments table is sufficient. If you're returning rows from the comments table, just use the JOIN statement.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Which is going to be a unique identifier? The user_id, I'd bet, or you can't have two "John Smith"s in your system.

And if volume is much of a concern, text matching the username field is going to be more expensive than linking to the users table in your query in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Numeric values are cheaper to join and index than an alphanumeric id. Use a number to uniquely identify a row. Another benefit is that the PK doesn't need to change if they need to change the user id. The last benefit is that this is the design of most modern web frameworks such as django and rails.